# Probability Notation Question, Distribution of a function of Random Variables

Tags: probability

What is the meaning of $P(Y\le y)$ in simplest terms? I am having trouble understanding random variables and when they are used. What is the difference of random variable and functions? I was having trouble understanding the following problem:

[image]

My understanding is:

In the solution it looks like they replace $Y$ with $X^3$, and then take a cube root. That value is the upper limit of integration, but why id $0$ the lower limit? The integrand is $f(x)$. So the integral of the pdf is the cdf. Where does the $0<y<1$ come from? Is that part just necessary to show that a probability must be between $0$ and $1$?

I feel lost with the big idea, can someone give me some pointers, and what I should be thinking when I look at the above mentioned notation and problem?

THANK YOU!

Comment: If you're studying probability and are learning about transformations *and* you don't know what a random variable is by now, you have a significant review to do.

Comment: Please be more constructive with your comment, it may help to keep this in mind:Your Answer
Thanks for contributing an answer to Mathematics Stack Exchange!

Please be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share your research!

Comment: There is a reason why I have a comment here rather than an answer. You are asking about a topic which is covered at the end of an undergraduate-level probability course and yet you do not understand what a random variable is, which is taught at the very beginning of such a course. I see further of evidence of this similarly, considering that you do not know how to read $P(Y \leq y)$. 

It is like asking a question on solving a calculus problem without knowing algebra. Hence, I suggested that you review your concepts. I'm not going to proceed further with this discussion.

Comment: Imagine that salt crystals are cubical, and let $X$ be the side length of a randomly chosen crystal. Since $Y=X^3$, the random variable $Y$ represents the volume of a randomly chosen crystal. Then for any fixed $y$, $\Pr(Y\le y)$ is the probability that a randomly chosen crystal has volume $\le y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My understanding is:
>
> In the solution it looks like they replace $Y$ with $X^3$, and then take a cube root. That value is the upper limit of integration, but why id $0$ the lower limit?

$0$ is the lower limit of the support for $f_X(x)$.  For all $x<0$, $f_X(x)=0$.

> The integrand is $f(x)$. So the integral of the pdf is the cdf. Where does the $0<y<1$ come from? Is that part just necessary to show that a probability must be between 0 and 1?

The support for $\,f_X(x)\,$ is $\;0<x<1\;$, so $\;0^3<x^3<1^3\;$ and since $\,y=x^3\,$ thus $\;0<y<1$ is the support for $F_Y(y)$.

Comment: is the support the domain? and how do you read $f_X(x)$ aloud?

Comment: @Guest The **support** of a random variable is the range of values where the probability density is not zero. Also $f_X(x)$ would be read aloud as "$f$ of capital $X$ at $x$".

Comment: Notation-wise, is using f(y) correct? My textbook switches to g.

Comment: @Guest, No, you should not use the same symbol for the density functions of two random variables with different distributions as they will not be the same function.  Either use a different symbol, such as $f, g$, or use subscripts to distinguish, such as $f_X, f_Y$.

Comment: So the solution of the given example is notationally incorrect?

Comment: @Guest Oh, yes.  It's definitely poor form.